# Capybara Testing: Clicking on button does not work properly

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am writing feature test using capybara, where I have to check each button for functionality. Actually, I am testing the following feature:
[feature for testing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StaVV.png)

I tried to find last delete icon on the table and click on it, however the dialog bar does not appear. My test scenario :

```
scenario 'delete button ' do

      # click on delete icon does not work 
      (page.all('.table_amenities tr').last).find(".amenity_action>button", visible: false).click
      expect(page).to have_content '削除してもよろしいですか?'
    end
```

Javascript code of this feature:

```
    template#room-amenities-template
  div[v-if="permissions[0]"]
    #room-amenities-dialog
      |  {{ window.I18n.dialogs.delete_confirmation }}
    .search_date
      router-link[to="/buildings"]
        span.but_choice.hvr-fade
          i.fa.fa-home[aria-hidden="true"]
          |  {{ window.I18n.activerecord.models.building }}
      a
        span.but_choice_active
          i.fa.fa-list[aria-hidden="true"]
          |  {{ window.I18n.activerecord.models.room_amenity }}
      router-link[to="/room_types"]
        span.but_choice.hvr-fade
          i.fa.fa-bars[aria-hidden="true"]
          |  {{ window.I18n.activerecord.models.room_type }}
      router-link[v-if="permissions[1]" to="/room_amenities/new"]
        span#new-room-amenity.but_save.hvr-fade
          i.fa.fa-plus[aria-hidden="true"]
          |  {{ window.I18n.buttons.new }}
    .for_table_amenities
      table.table_amenities[width="80%" border="1px solid #313131;"]
        tr
          th.amenity_number
            | {{ window.I18n.support.tables.num }}
          th.amenity_title
            | {{ window.I18n.activerecord.models.room_amenity }}
          th.amenity_action
            | {{ window.I18n.support.tables.actions}}
        tr[v-for="(roomAmenity, index) in roomAmenities"]
          td
            | {{ index + 1 }}
          td.amenity_title
            | {{ roomAmenity.title }}
          td.amenity_action
            template[v-if="permissions[2]"]
              router-link[:to= "{ path: '/room_amenities/' + roomAmenity.id }"]
                button.btn-link
                  i.fa.fa-pencil[aria-hidden="true"]
              template[v-if="permissions[3] && roomAmenity.rooms.length === 0"]
                | |
                button.btn-link[@click= "promptRemove (index, roomAmenity.id)"]
                  i.fa.fa-trash.delete_from_table[aria-hidden="true"]
```

Html code of this table:

```
<td>4</td>
<td class="amenity_title">Refrigerator</td>
<td class="amenity_action">
  <a href="/room_amenities/4" class=""> 
    <button class="btn-link"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil">  </i></button></a>
   |
 <button class="btn-link"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash delete_from_table"></i></button>
```

Does anybody have an idea why dialog bar could not appear on delete icon click?

Answer (score 0):

You can't click on non-visible items, so passing the `visible: false` option and then calling click on the resultant element makes no sense.  Additionally you want to pass a `minimum: 1` option to the `all` call to make sure the table has actually loaded, or use a css selector like :last-child rather than `all`.  Something like

```
page.find('.table_amenities tbody tr:last-child').find(".amenity_action > button:last-child).click
```

should work.  If that doesn't work, then check for JS errors that are preventing the click handler from happening.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do  you get an error on the click, or does the content expectation fail? Or something else?

Comment: delete button click does not trigger dialog bar appearance

Comment: @A.B ok - looking at your table HTML there is no inline click handler - what templating system are you using that takes `[@click=` to be an event binding?

Comment: vue.js , click binded to the method promptRemove (index, roomAmenity.id) and this method's content is as follow:'promptRemove: `function (index, id) {
      $("#room-amenities-dialog")
        .data("index", index)
        .data("id", id)
        .dialog("open");
    }`